# Android Studio breakpoint cross explanation

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm debugging my Android project in Android Studio using breakpoints.

I've noticed sometimes my breakpoints have a cross in them and don't pause execution.

On the intellij site this is explained as: *"Shows when the breakpoint is set on a commented or non-executable line indicating that such breakpoint would not be hit."*

Could anyone tell me how the above summary can explain the behaviour of the following breakpoints:

[image]

Why does the second breakpoint have a tick? I'm confused!

Comment: The explanation does not apply to your `Log.i()` statement. Could be a bug with Android Studio itself if it thinks a codes line is a comment line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's usually because the code on the connected device is different than the code on your screen.

In different words, the debugger "knows" where a break point is based on the line number on the code, so you probably added lines of code, and by that moved the line position a few lines down.

Super simple way to fix that is compile the code and flash again on the device.

Comment: Answer is 100% correct, just make sure that in your gradle file, you have minifyEnabled as false. Like `buildTypes { debug { minifyEnabled false } }`

Comment: In my case I had minifyEnabled true even in my debug setup, therefore the breakpoints were crossed and an unhelpful tooltip just said "line numbers not available". I could guess it was related to minify, but if I hadn't known about minification of JS code, I would never have figured it out :)