# How to debuge through Breakpoints in Android Studio?

Tags: debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

[image]

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1

1.
In above image, at debugging time the cursor goes through breakpoints only those have that the 
Correct Symbol.

2.
And not going to next breakpoint .

Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Probably you have an older version of the app in your device and you can't reach that breakpoints. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040220/android-studio-breakpoint-cross-explanation                                                                                                                -above link give me some help to understand about breakpoint ....thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You have an older version of the app in your device and you can't reach that breakpoints because the code has been changed.

Reinstall the app and try again.